# Kivy spinner - Dynamically switch dropdown contents in Python code

Tags: python, kivy, spinner

I have a screen with a few widgets, including a Spinner. Within my Python code, I'm trying to alter these (background color, color, text, etc.). Everything works as I want except the Spinner. Within the Class, I set the value and it is reflected in the GUI, but when I then add a value in a one of its method, the Spinner in the GUI does not change. I've spent several hours searching for a solution and have tried several variations with no success. I fear that I'm lost and perhaps confused as to Namespaces or something. Any guidance would be appreciated.

I'm including four items to try and show my problem: 2 Python files, a KIVY file and the printed results of running the code. I apologize for the size of the example, but I was afraid to try and cut it down further and inadvertently introduce "fake problems" into the discussion. (The actual source is over 2K lines. . .

```
# Global.py
# Separate file to hold the shared variables and constants

from collections import deque

import vlc

# for screenmanager ----------------------------------------
_scrWelcome = 0
_scrMainScreen = 1
_scrPlayer = 2
_scrDetails = 3
_scrConvert = 4
_scrExplorer = 5
_scrMaint = 6

# colors --------------------------------------------------
_black = (0, 0, 0, 1)
_blue = (0, 0, 1, 1)                    # toggle btns
_bluecadet = (95,158,160, 1)
_bluedodger = (30/255, 144/255, 1, 1)
_bluesky = (135/255, 206/255, 250/255,1)
_greenlawn = (124/255, 252/255, 0, 1)

# database ------------------------------------------------------------
db_conn = None          # connection to the database
db_entry=[]             # list containing one record from the database
                        #       (format depends on the table)
db_keys = {}            # {item, dbkey} for Albums, Artists, Genres, Grafix filled from The_DB
db_Dkeys = {}           # holds keys for Details screen fields

rsMtitles = deque()     # collection holding music titles
rsTheArtist=[]          # list holding results from Artists query:
                        #       [[key, artist name, artist sortname,artist photo key]]
rsTheGrafix=[]          # list holding results from Grafix query 
                        #       [[[key, name, whatkind, path]]]
rstitles = deque()      # collection of artist names, genre literals,
                        #        or album titles

# Booleans -----------------------------------------------------------------
its_bad=False           # problem with something
its_empty = False       # some db query found no records
```

```
"""Music Manager

This script provides the user with a complete tool for managing and 
manipulating the files in his/her music colletion.
"""

import Global
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
from collections import deque

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, BooleanProperty, NumericProperty, DictProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserIconView, FileChooserListView
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import (ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition, SlideTransition, CardTransition, SwapTransition, FadeTransition,WipeTransition, FallOutTransition, RiseInTransition)
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
# ======================================================================
Window.size = (1600,900)
Window.maximize()
MusicMan = Builder.load_file('import os.kv')
if Global.tracing:
        print('KV file loaded')
# ============================================================================

class Screenmgt(ScreenManager):
    dartist = ObjectProperty()
    dartistpix = ObjectProperty()
    dfile = ObjectProperty()
    dgenre = ObjectProperty()
    dnewfile = ObjectProperty()
    dnewpath = ObjectProperty()
    dpath = ObjectProperty()
    dsaartist = ObjectProperty()
    dsartist = ObjectProperty()
    dsgenre = ObjectProperty()
    dtrack = ObjectProperty()
    genrelist = ObjectProperty()
    genrename = ObjectProperty()
    imgname = ObjectProperty()
    ldirpick = ObjectProperty()
    if Global.tracing:
            print('ScreenManager class instanciated')

class The_DB():
    """Class for handling all database interaction.
    
    The_DB has the following methods:
        create_connection
        create_database
        get_album
        get_artist
        get_control
        getgenre
        get_grafix
        get_music
        put_album
        put_artist
        put_control
        put_genre
        put_grafix
        put_music.

        Each of the record retrieval routines, with the exception of get_control,
        fills a global recordset with all records returned by the SQL query. In 
        addition, each also creates a global dictionary of "names" and their keys, 
        (db_keys, db_Mkeys) and a list of the "names" (rstitles, rsMtitles)
     """

    global mystack
    
    sqlstr=''
    
    Global.its_bad = False

    if Global.tracing:
        print('in The_DB')

    def create_connection():
        """ create a database connection to a SQLite database. """
        if Global.tracing:
            print('The_DB - connect')
        if Global.tracing:
             print('         connecting to ', Global.user_fulldb)
        try:
            Global.user_dbconn = sqlite3.connect(Global.user_fulldb)
            if Global.tracing:
                 print('       db connected')
            Global.thecurse = Global.user_dbconn.cursor()
        except Error as e:
            print('DB not connected: ', e)
            Global.its_bad = True
        if mystack[len(mystack)-1] == 'Welcome_check_user_3':
            iwelcome.check_user_4()
        elif mystack[len(mystack)-1] == 'Welcome:create_user_2':
            iwelcome.create_user_3

    def get_grafix(which_one=None, what_for = 'Both'):
        """ Retrieve one or more album entries. 
        
        parameters:
            which_one = key of record to retrieve; NONE means all
            what_for = what is the type of grafix (album or artist or both)
        results:
            If no entries are found, sets its_empty to TRUE.
            If the query fails, sets its_bad to TRUE; otherwise sets
                db_keys = a dictionary of Grafix names and their database keys [title][key]
                rsTitles = a collection of grafix names
                rsTheGrafix = list of the retrieved entries (full database entry)
            Sets dbevnt to announce completion.
        """
        if Global.tracing:
            print('get grafix: caller = ', mystack[len(mystack)-1])
        Global.rstitles.clear()
        Global.db_entry.clear()
        Global.rsTheGrafix.clear()
        Global.db_keys = {}
        sqlstr = 'SELECT * FROM Grafixs'
        if which_one is None:
            if what_for == 'Album:':
                sqlstr = sqlstr + ' WHERE WhatIAm = 1'
            elif what_for == 'Artist':
                sqlstr = sqlstr + ' WHERE WhatIAm = 2'
        else:
            sqlstr = sqlstr + ' WHERE MyID = ' + str(which_one)
        if Global.tracing:
            print('SQL = , sqlstr)
        try:
            cursor = Global.user_dbconn.execute(sqlstr)
            i = 4 #len(cursor.fetchall())
            if i > 0:
                Global.its_empty = False
                for row in cursor:
                    Global.rstitles.append(row[1])
                    Global.db_keys[str(row[1])] = row[0]
                    Global.db_entry.append([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]])
                                    # MyID, MyName, WhatIAm, WhereIAm
            else:
                Global.its_empty = True
        except:
            print('Grafix query failed')
            Global.rsTheGrafix = [[[0,None, None, None]]]
            Global.its_bad = True
        else:
            Global.rsTheGrafix = Global.db_entry.copy()
            if Global.tracing:
                print('\nGetGrafix returning rsTheGrafix: ', Global.rsTheGrafix)
                print('\nGetGrafix returning db_keys: ', Global.db_keys)
                print('\nGetGrafix returning rstitles:', Global.rstitles)
        if mystack[len(mystack)-1] == 'MusicLoader:fill_details_3':
            imusicloader.fill_details_4()
          elif mystack[len(mystack)-1] == 'Maint:set_newalbum_2':
            imaint.set_newalbum_3()
        elif mystack[len(mystack)-1] == 'Maint:add_thepicture_2':
            imaint.add_the_picture_3()
            
class Maint(Screen):
    """ Class for adding albums, artists, picture information and genres.
    
    These modules are also used by the Music Details screen (scrDetails)
    when, in the course of adding music, the user needs to add one or
    more of these items.

    Modules are:
        add_thealbum
        add_newalbum
        add_thegenre
        add_newpicture
        set_newalbum
        set_newartist
        set_newgenre
        set_newpicture
    """

    daartistname = ObjectProperty()
 #   dartistpix = ObjectProperty()
    spinnerfiller = ObjectProperty()
    artistsfill = ListProperty()

    if Global.tracing:
        print('in Maint')
    spinnerfiller = []
    artistsfill = ['x','y']
    print ('entering ', dartistpix.values)
#    print('first set ', Global.theroot.screens[Global._scrMaint].dartistpix.values)
    artistsfill = ['6','9']
#    print('second set ', Global.theroot.screens[Global._scrMaint].dartistpix.values)
    strwhat = ''

    myevnta = Event()
    myevntg = Event()

    def set_newartist(self):
        """ expose the screen's fields relative to adding an artist."""
        self.artistsfill.append('q')
        if Global.tracing:
                print('Maint - set_newalbum artistsfill = ', self.artistsfill)
        mystack.append('Maint:set_newartist')
        self.addartist.background_color = Global._bluedodger
        self.addartist.text = 'Add the Artist'
        self.dartist.background_color = Global._white
        self.dartistpix.background_color = Global._bluedodger
        self.dartistsort.background_color = Global._white
        self.spinnerfiller.append ('New Picture')
        The_DB.get_grafix(None, 'Artist')

   def set_newartist_2(self):
        mystack.pop()
        if Global.tracing:
            print('Maint:set_newartist_2; back from get_Grafix artistsfill = ', self.artistsfill)
        self.dartistpix.values = self.artistsfill
        if Global.its_empty:
            Global.its_empty = False
            print('no artists pictures found')
        elif Global.its_bad:              # failed to get the pictures
            Global.my_mess = 'No pictures found'
            Popups.show_popup()
            Global.its_bad = False
        else:
            x = 0
            print('dartistpix.values =',self.dartistpix.values)
            Global.drop_artists = []
            while x < len(Global.rsTheGrafix):
                Global.drop_artists.append(Global.rsTheGrafix[x][1])
                x +=1
        print('\ndrop_artists = ',Global.drop_artists)
        self.dartistpix.values = Global.drop_artists 
        print('\ndartistpix.values = ',self.dartistpix.values)
        self.artistsfill = Global.drop_artists
        print('artistsfill = ', self.artistsfill
        self.dartistsort.background_color = Global._white
        self.dlartistpix.bcolor = Global._bluedodger
        self.dlartistpix.text = 'Artists Picture'
        self.dlartistsort.bcolor = Global._bluedodger
        self.dlartistsort.text = 'Artists sort name'
        self.dlnewartist.bcolor = Global._bluecadet
        self.dlnewartist.text = 'Artist Name'
```

```
os.kv

#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#: import Global Global
#: import Popup kivy.uix.popup
#: import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
#: import CheckBox kivy.uix.checkbox

#:set color_button (0.784, 0.443, 0.216, 1)  # brown
#:set c_black (0, 0, 0, 1)      # black
#:set c_blue (0, 0, 1, 1)       # toggle btns
#:set c_bluecadet (95/255,158/255,160/255,1)    # maint screen
#:set c_bluedodger (30/255, 144/255, 1, 1)
#:set c_greenlawn (124/255, 252/255, 0, 1)

<Screenmgt>:
    id: sm
    transition: FadeTransition()

<MySpinnerOption@SpinnerOption>:
    height: 30

<Maint>:
    addalbum: btnAddAlbum
    addartist: btnAddArtist
    addgenre: btnAddGenre
    addpix: btnAddPix
    anewalbum: btnNewAlbum
    anewartist: btnNewArtist
    anewgenre: btnNewGenre
    anewpix: btnNewGrafix
    compilation: chkComp
    dalbumart: CoverSpinner
    dalbumname: txtAlbumName
    dartist: txtArtistName
    daartistname: ArtistSpinner
    dartistpix: PixSpinner
    dartistsort: txtSortName
    dartpath: ArtSpinner
    dgenrename: txtGenreName
    dvalue: txValue
    dlalbumart: lblAlbumArt
    dlalbumname: lblNewAlbum
    dlalbumtype: lblAlbumType
    dlartistname: lblAlbumArtist
    dlartistpix: lblArtistPix
    dlartistsort: lblArtistSort
    dlnewartist: lblNewArtist
    dlnewgenre: lblNewGenre
    dlpixpath: lblPixPath
    dlvalue:lblValue
    finishup: btnFinish
    itsanalbum: chkalbum
    itsanartist:chkartist
    newpix:imgpix
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: c_bluecadet
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    FloatLayout:
    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - new artist - - - - - - - - - -
        Button:
            id: btnNewArtist
            background_color: c_bluedodger
            text: 'an artist'
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.03
            pos_hint: {'x':0.1, 'top':.7}
            on_release: root.set_newartist()
        # . . . . . . . . . . . new artist fields . . . . . .
        LabelB:
            id: lblNewArtist
            bcolor: c_bluecadet
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.03
            text: 'artistname'
            pos_hint: {'x':.1, 'top': .66}
        TextInput:
            id: txtArtistName
            background_color: c_bluecadet
            text: 'artistnametxt'
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.04
            pos_hint: {'x':0.2, 'top': 0.66}
            on_text:
        LabelB:
            id: lblArtistSort
            bcolor: c_bluecadet
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.03
            text: 'sortname'
            pos_hint: {'x':.1, 'top': .62}
        TextInput:
            id: txtSortName
            background_color: c_bluecadet
            text: 'sortnametxt'
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.04
            pos_hint: {'x':0.2, 'top': 0.62}
            on_text:
        LabelB:
            id: lblArtistPix
            bcolor: c_bluecadet
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.03
            text: 'artistpixlbl'
            pos_hint: {'x':.1, 'top': .58}
        Spinner:
            id: PixSpinner
            text: ''
            background_color: c_bluecadet
            color: c_redscr
            values: root.artistsfill
            size_hint: None, None
            size: (235, 38)
            option_cls: Factory.MySpinnerOption
            sync_height: True
            pos_hint:{'center_x': .280, 'center_y': .55}
            on_text: 
        Button:
            id: btnAddArtist
            background_color: c_bluecadet
            text: 'addartistnow'
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.03
            pos_hint: {'x':0.25, 'top': 0.50}
            on_release: 
                mystack = 'Screen'
                root.set_newartist()
```

printout

KV file loaded

ScreenManager class instanciated

in The_DB

in Maint

entering  ['x', 'y']

entering2  ['6', '9']        ***<----this appears in the GUI***

in MainScreen

The_DB - connect

```
     connecting to  G:\Projects\Python\MusicMan\TheMusic.db

   db connected
```

Maint - set_newalbum artistsfill =  ['6', '9', 'q']       <--***this does not appear in the GUI***

get grafix: caller =  Maint:set_newartist

SQL = SELECT * FROM Grafixs WHERE WhatIAm = 2

GetGrafix returning rsTheGrafix:  [[19, 'Beatles.jpg', 2, H:\OurSightsSounds\Audio\Music\AllBsmusic\AlbumArt\'],[9, 'Adele.jpg', 2, 'H:\OurSightsSounds\Audio\Music\AllBsmusic\AlbumArt\'],[8, 'ABBA.jpg', 2, 'H:\OurSightsSounds\Audio\Music\AllBsmusic\AlbumArt\'],[10, 'Air Supply.jpg']]

GetGrafix returning db_keys:  {'Beatles.jpg': 19, 'Adele.jpg': 9, 'ABBA.jpg': 8, 'Air Supply.jpg': 10}

GetGrafix returning rstitles: deque(['Beatles.jpg', 'Adele.jpg', 'ABBA.jpg', 'Air Supply.jpg'])

Maint:set_newartist_2; back from get_Grafix artistsfill =  ['6', '9', 'q'] ***<-GUI does not reflect***

dartistpix.values = ['6', '9', 'q'] ***<-- GUI does not reflect***

drop_artists =  ['Beatles.jpg', 'Adele.jpg', 'ABBA.jpg', 'Air Supply.jpg']

dartistpix.values =  ['Beatles.jpg', 'Adele.jpg', 'ABBA.jpg', 'Air Supply.jpg] ***<--GUI does not reflect***

artistsfill =  ['Beatles.jpg', 'Adele.jpg', 'ABBA.jpg', 'Air Supply.jpg'] ***<--GUI does not reflect***
,
***At this point, the GUI still shows 6, 9***

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while you have correctly defined `artistsfill` with the code:

```
artistsfill = ListProperty()
```

and set up its use in the `kv`:

```
values: root.artistsfill
```

the lines of code:

```
artistsfill = ['x','y']
```

and:

```
artistsfill = ['6','9']
```

redefine `artistsfill` as a simple `list`. Since it is no longer a `ListProperty`, changes to a simple list will not be reflected in the `Spinner` where `artistsfill` is used.

Changes to `artistsfill` must be made inside methods, so that they do not redefine the `artistsfill` attribute.

Comment: I commented out the two lines you cited in your answer and, my printout now shows that the Spinner has a "q" for a value which wasn't happening before. I thought we had it, but then the screen still had only a "q' after the code completed.